# Solr score keyword detection rate

Tags: solr

I'm used Solr 6.1

I'm setting the score now,

But I have some issue on score

I just search GCS, the qf set is: title^100 content^70 text^50,

The three fields type all are text_general,

I get first one result score is 1050.8486 and another is 853.08655,

But the first one content is so short in content field and another one is so many in content field,

I just not know why the first score will be many

Two results debugquery content below:

1002.8741 = sum of:\n  1002.8741 = max of:\n    1002.8741 = weight(title:GCS in 1275) [], result of:\n      1002.8741 = score(doc=1275,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        100.0 = boost\n        8.513557 = idf(docFreq=27, docCount=137000)\n        1.177973 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.75 = parameter b\n          6.3423285 = avgFieldLength\n          4.0 = fieldLength\n    928.3479 = weight(content:GCS in 1275) [], result of:\n      928.3479 = score(doc=1275,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n        70.0 = boost\n        7.1785564 = idf(docFreq=104, docCount=137000)\n        1.8474623 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.75 = parameter b\n          176.37256 = avgFieldLength\n          16.0 = fieldLength\n

---

811.1335 = sum of:\n  811.1335 = max of:\n    127.21202 = weight(text:GCS in 9400) [], result of:\n      127.21202 = score(doc=9400,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        50.0 = boost\n        7.464645 = idf(docFreq=78, docCount=137000)\n        0.3408388 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.75 = parameter b\n          44.69738 = avgFieldLength\n          256.0 = fieldLength\n    811.1335 = weight(title:GCS in 9400) [], result of:\n      811.1335 = score(doc=9400,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        100.0 = boost\n        8.513557 = idf(docFreq=27, docCount=137000)\n        0.9527551 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.75 = parameter b\n          6.3423285 = avgFieldLength\n          7.111111 = fieldLength\n    174.06395 = weight(content:GCS in 9400) [], result of:\n      174.06395 = score(doc=9400,freq=7.0 = termFreq=7.0\n), product of:\n        70.0 = boost\n        7.1785564 = idf(docFreq=104, docCount=137000)\n        0.34639663 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          7.0 = termFreq=7.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.75 = parameter b\n          176.37256 = avgFieldLength\n          7281.778 = fieldLength\n

===========================================================================

I have another question when I use shards the omitNorms it'll not work? why? I found short content score more to long content? the schema is same

First one is from A collection is short content,The other one is B collection and long content :

1158.9161 = sum of:\n  1158.9161 = max of:\n    1158.9161 = weight(title:boeing in 52601) [], result of:\n      1158.9161 = score(doc=52601,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        100.0 = boost\n        11.589161 = idf(docFreq=5, docCount=593568)\n        1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n    1085.6042 = weight(content:boeing in 52601) [], result of:\n      1085.6042 = score(doc=52601,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n        70.0 = boost\n        11.279006 = idf(docFreq=7, docCount=593568)\n        1.375 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n

---

1060.8777 = sum of:\n  1060.8777 = max of:\n    433.1234 = weight(text:boeing in 39406) [], result of:\n      433.1234 = score(doc=39406,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        50.0 = boost\n        8.662468 = idf(docFreq=112, docCount=650450)\n        1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n    884.746 = weight(title:boeing in 39406) [], result of:\n      884.746 = score(doc=39406,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n        100.0 = boost\n        8.84746 = idf(docFreq=93, docCount=650450)\n        1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n    1060.8777 = weight(content:boeing in 39406) [], result of:\n      1060.8777 = score(doc=39406,freq=7.0 = termFreq=7.0\n), product of:\n        70.0 = boost\n        8.069756 = idf(docFreq=203, docCount=650450)\n        1.8780489 = tfNorm, computed from:\n          7.0 = termFreq=7.0\n          1.2 = parameter k1\n          0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underline similarity Solr 6.1 uses is BM25[1] .

This means the field value length in comparison to the average field length is important.
Being more specific, you are using the dismax and you keep in consideration just purely the maximum.
So exploring the maximums :

**First document Max:**

1002.8741 = weight(title:GCS in 1275) [], result of:\n 1002.8741 = score(doc=1275,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n 100.0 = boost\n 8.513557 = idf(docFreq=27, docCount=137000)\n 1.177973 = tfNorm, computed from:\n 1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n 1.2 = parameter k1\n 0.75 = parameter b\n 6.3423285 = avgFieldLength\n **4.0 = fieldLength**\n

**Second document Max:**

811.1335 = weight(title:GCS in 9400) [], result of:\n 811.1335 = score(doc=9400,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n 100.0 = boost\n 8.513557 = idf(docFreq=27, docCount=137000)\n 0.9527551 = tfNorm, computed from:\n 1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n 1.2 = parameter k1\n 0.75 = parameter b\n 6.3423285 = avgFieldLength\n **7.111111 = fieldLength**\n

So the shorter first document title makes the winner.
You can play with the dismax/edismax to take in consideration also other factors and not only the maximum[2].

Regards

[1] http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thetie_TieBreaker_Parameter

Comment: Ho can I settting for this?
did you have example?

Comment: What do you mean ?
You can do a lot relevancy wise :
- you can write your own custom similarity class

- you can fine tune boosting to get the score you want
- play with query parsers ect ect

But your question was to understand what was happening, wasn't it ?

Comment: Yes,I'm understand what was happening now,but how to fix it? I just no have idea

Comment: I has study this problem is because BM 25, if I want just use keyword of match frequency to get calculation,how to do it?

Comment: You mean you want ti ignore the field length ?
You can omit norms calculation at indexing time.
Setting in the schema :

omitNorms
If true, omits the norms associated with this field (this disables length normalization for the field, and saves some memory). Defaults to true for all primitive (non-analyzed) field types, such as int, float, data, bool, and string. Only full-text fields or fields need norms.

Comment: yes, but the title, content and text field is text_general type, so I need to setting the omitNorms to true and reindex?

Comment: Thank you so much, it has fixed.

Comment: I have another question when I use shards the omitNorms it'll not work? why? I found short content score more to long content? the schema is same

Comment: sorry the info was too long, so I post it to the question

Comment: Please, read more carefully the debug query explanation.
It is not the norms that make the difference in this second comparison :

1060.8777 = weight(content:boeing in 39406) - product of:\n 70.0 = boost\n 8.069756 = idf(docFreq=203, docCount=650450)\n 1.8780489 = tfNorm, computed from:\n 7.0 = termFreq=7.0\n ...

1158.9161 = weight(title:boeing in 52601)  =  product of:\n 100.0 = boost\n 11.589161 = idf(docFreq=5, docCount=593568)\n 1.0 = tfNorm, computed from:\n 1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n 1.2 = parameter k1\n 0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n

it is IDF, TF and different boost.

Comment: sorry,...I don't understand what's that mean?

Comment: I think is because IDF. can I just use TF to calculation score, how? and I've use shards to search multiple collection, But I think it does not together to do the calculation. why?